# Preventing Web Browser–to–Native App Handoff

Tags: ios, mobile, mobile-safari, handoff, ios8-handoff

Let's assume you have a mobile web app under the domain `mobile.example.com` and a desktop web-app under the domain `example.com`.

Web Browser–to–Native App Handoff is working and catches all the routes under those domains.

If you manually visit `mobile.example.com`, all subsequent links under that domain remain within Mobile Safari, as they should. You then encounter a link to `example.com` which would under normal circumstances, render responsively in Mobile Safari. With Handoff enabled, it opens with the Native app.

Is there a way to work around this behavior and keep it within Mobile Safari?